# Installing Software asking for password

Tags: package-management, permissions, password, users

I'm running Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I have two accounts: 
- The first as an administrator (Password is required for login)
- The second as a normal user (Without password)

The administrator can install, update, or remove packages. The second account can't do that without the admin password. I want to allow to the second account to install, remove, or update a package without the administrator password.

I tried to add the user `sudo` group and first account group then I test it. It doesn't work. Whenever I'm trying to install software from the second account, I'm getting a pop up:

> "Authentication Required"
>   Authentication is required to install, update, or remove a package

I tried the administrator password but it doesn't work! 
Any idea how can I solve the issue?

Comment: There is no way to solve it. If you want to allow another user to install software, then give them administrative rights and set a password. Installing software without asking for a password is a really bad practice.

Comment: @Pilot6 I was going to say the same thing. Consider turning your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to solve it. If you want to allow another user to install software, then give them administrative rights and set a password. Installing software without asking for a password is a really bad practice.